# Sporadic loss of access to local server

Tags: macos, networking, curl, hostname

For some reason, I lose access to a local server called `lux-app04` seemingly at random, but only in some applications.  As you can see in the image below, Postman (top) can connect to it, but curl (below) cannot even resolve the host.  They both usually work.

Only way I can fix this is restarting my computer. What might be causing this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What happens when you try to use its IP instead of hostname in curl?

Comment: Sorry, I will have to wait for the problem to return before I try it with the IP address.  Will comment when complete.

Comment: Problem sprung up again today.  Curl is failing with hostname, but succeeding with the IP address.

Comment: Very interesting. I think we're facing a problem with NetBIOS... Is the network utilizing a WINS server? Sounds like it could be a misconfigured entry somewhere in there?